# Help with building object model

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

Help me with building object model, please.

I need abstract class `Unit` representing each military unit in a game. There is `Soldier`, `Tank`, `Jet` and `Bunker` (children of Unit). Each of them has `int` properties `Count` and `Defense`, constructor with single `int count` parameter and one method `GetTotalDefense`.

My idea is following.

```
private abstract class Unit
{
    private int Count { get; set; }
    private const int Defense = 0;

    protected Unit(int count)
    {
        Count = count;
    }

    public int GetTotalDefense()
    {
        return Count * Defense;
    }
}

private class Tank : Unit
{
    private const int Defense = 5;
}
```

Each unit has different `Count` and different `Defense`. Body of constructor and body of `GetTotalDefense` is always the same. **What I need** is in child class override `Defense`, because each unit has different. This property should be const, all instances of Tank (Soldier, ...) has same defense. Is there a possibility to inherit const property or each child needs its own const `Defense` property?

And here is an example I'd like to achieve.

Oh, there is also class Troop

```
public class Troop
{
    private Soldier Soldiers { get; set; }
    private Tank Tanks { get; set; }
    private Jet Jets { get; set; }
    private Fort Forts { get; set; }

    public Troop(int soldiers, int tanks, int jets, int forts)
    {
        Soldiers = new Soldier(soldiers);
        Tanks = new Tank(tanks);
        Jets = new Jet(jets);
        Forts = new Fort(forts);
    }

    public int GetTotalDefense()
    {
        return Soldiers.GetTotalDefense() + Tanks.GetTotalDefense() + Jets.GetTotalDefense() + Forts.GetTotalDefense();
    }
}
```

Also, **feel free to suggest better solution**, thanks.

PS: I'm really strict about access modifiers, so be precise in your examples, thank you.

Comment: Why be strict about your access modifiers if you have `get; set;` on each of them?

Comment: Exaplain me please. When is property private, there is no need get; set;?

Comment: I think glowcoder his saying that if you have the get and set on a property you can do your validation in that so why do you need to be strict?  Also are you aware you can do `public int Count {get; private set;}`? To get a publicly readable, privately writeable property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really use a const but you can make a readonly property also are you sure you want the classes to be private and not internal or public?

```
public abstract class Unit { 

    protected Unit(int count) {
      Count=count;
    }

    protected int Count { get; private set; }
    protected abstract int Defense {get;}

    public int TotalDefense {
      get { return Count*Defense; }
    }

}

public class Tank : Unit {

   public Tank(int count) : base(count) {}

   protected override int Defense {
     get { return 5; }
   }
}

public class Troop {

   private Unit[] Troops;

   public Troop(int soldiers, int tanks, int jets, int forts) {
     Troops = new Unit[] {
                new Soldier(soldiers),
                new Tank(tanks),
                new Jet(jets),
                new Fort(forts)
              };
   }

   // The using System.Linq you can do
   public int TotalDefense {
     get { return Troops.Sum(x=>x.TotalDefense);}
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't need them public and I don't know internal modifier, so private is my choice :)

Comment: Not working choice :D Is `internal` solution for disable acces to class from another namespace?

Comment: Btw, is it better make property instead of method? Why is that? I'm talking about `TotalDefense` property in class `Troop`.

Comment: @Andrew private means only the class itself can access it, protected means only the class and items that inherit from it, internal means only items within the same assembly.

Comment: @Andrew from the [microsoft guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzwdh01d(v=vs.71).aspx#cpconpropertyusageguidelinesanchor1) you should use properties for data and methods for actions. Also if you ever came to use WPF binding (I know its unlikely with your game!) then you can't bind to a method but you can to a property.

Comment: And assembly means namespace?

Comment: I'm using WPF binding, actually :-) Thank you very much.

Comment: No, assembly means binary/project.

Answer (score 0):

Although this solution does not use const, it achieves what you want:

```
internal abstract class Unit
{
    private int Count { get; set; }
    private int Defense { get; set; }
    public int TotalDefense { get { return Count * Defense; } }

    protected Unit(int defense, int count)
    {
        Defense = defense;
        Count = count;
    }
}

internal class Tank : Unit
{
    protected Tank(int count)
        : base(5, count)  // you can use a const variable instead of 5
    {
    }
}
```

Or maybe this is more suitable:

```
internal abstract class Unit 
{ 
    private int Count { get; set; } 
    public abstract int Defense { get; }
    public int TotalDefense { get { return Count * Defense; } }

    protected Unit(int count) 
    { 
        Count = count;
    }
} 

internal class Tank : Unit 
{
    override public int Defense { get { return 5; } }

    protected Tank(int count) : base(count)
    {
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is actually `readonly`.  Also, since `Defense` is used in subclasses, you need to make it protected.

```
private abstract class Unit  
{  
    private int _Count;  
    protected readonly const int Defense;

    public int TotalDefense
    { get { return Count * Defense; } }

    protected Unit (int count, int defense)
    {
        Defense = defense;
        _Count = count;
    }
}  

private class Tank : Unit  
{
    public Tank (int Count)
        : base (Count, 5)
    { }        
}

public class Troop
{
    public IEnumerable<Unit> Units { get; protected set; }

    public Troop (int soldiers, int tanks, int jets, int forts)
    {
        Troops = new Unit[]
        {
            new Soldier (soldiers),
            new Tank (tanks),
            new Jet (jets),
            new Fort (forts)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this (but this is in java)

```
abstract class Unit {
    Unit(int defense,int count) {
        this.defense = defense;
        this.count=count;
    }
    final int defense;
    int count;
}
class Soldier extends Unit {
    Soldier(int count) {
        super(1,count);
    }
}
class Tank extends Unit {
    Tank(int count) {
        super(5,count);
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Unit[] units = { new Soldier(2), new Tank(3) };
        for(Unit unit:units)
            System.out.println(unit.count+" "+unit.defense);
    }
}
```